# how to change a webbrowser's listbox defined in a user control from another form

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I've been trying to add items to a `listbox` defined in a HTML file,shown in a webbrowser.
I created this listbox  in a user control
I tried this code but I came up empty:

**My Code:**

```
public string _listBoxProperty
    {
        set { webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Select1").OuterHtml = value; }
         get { return webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Select1").OuterHtml; }
    }
```

Thank you profusely :)

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET?

Comment: I think he is doing winforms and using WebBrowser control.

Comment: @Igor then why would you want to change the contents of the HTML-file?

Comment: In fact,the Null Reference Exception occurred.

Comment: @bash.d - he is trying to change (or get html for) what is WebBrowser control is showing - using C# code.

Comment: @Pedram - can you show html for "Select1" element?

Comment: No,I am using a windows form which is supposed to load a web page using web browser,

Comment: HTML code
Select<select id="Select1" name="drop1" multiple="multiple" >
 <option value="0"></option>
 <option value="1">item 1</option>
 <option value="2">item 2</option>
</select>

Comment: C# code
String source = (@"D:\source.txt");
HtmlElement ls = doc.GetElementById("Select1");

I want to add items to this listbox in the form,it is currently in the user control

Comment: public string _listBoxProperty
    {
        set { webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Select1").OuterHtml = value; }
         get { return webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Select1").OuterHtml; }
    }
this should work because it adds to the usercontrols features in form
but when I run the program the error occurs

Comment: Please,if any one could fix this two lines I would be grateful
public string _listBoxProperty
    {
        set { webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Select1").OuterHtml = value; }
         get { return webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Select1").OuterHtml; }
    }

Comment: if you are getting Null Reference Exception, you need to find out what is null:  webBrowser1,  webBrowser1.Document or webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Select1")?

Comment: When the form is loading webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Select1") is null
how can I handle that null exception?

Comment: You don't handle this null exception - you check what GetElementById returns before using this returned value. "When the form is loading" is too early to access/manipulate content of document. See Sharique's answer and DocumentCompleted event of WebBrowser.

Comment: When I run the code this :"Object reference not set to an instance of an object." comes up and it is on this line:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Dose your web-browser located in a user control?and dose list box located in user control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

you can only modify on webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted else it will give you an error
this is property of webbrowser control you are using

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
    HtmlElement opt = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("option");
    HtmlElement ddlPopulate = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Select1");
    opt.InnerText = "TestValue";
    ddlPopulate.AppendChild(opt);
 }
```

Hope This Help.

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to add items in my form,I defined my webbrowser in usercontrol,

Comment: I think if you could just correct this code my problem would be fixed

Comment: @Pedram i modified my answer, have a look.

Comment: @Pedram have you added this line to your yourForm.Designer.cs this.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(this.webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);

Comment: @ShariqueAnsari I am really grateful,I guess if I add a little bit to it my problem would be solved,thanks

Comment: @Igor this is my tested code, i think this guy doing something wrong

Comment: @ShariqueAnsari:I guess the project I am working on is a bit complicated and  I could not mention my question correctly

Comment: The code you stated was really helpful but my issue still remains unsolved
public string _listBoxProperty
    {
        set { webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Select1").OuterHtml = value; }
         get { return webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Select1").OuterHtml; }
    }
I know this code would solve the prolbem if you look into it
I wrote it in the webbrowser which is in a usercontrol and know I am trying to call it from my main form
sorry for the complication